# Cocos2d , hd retina display iPad

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Do you have to update to the latest cocos2d to get ipad retina display and what suffix do you use for retina display on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

iPad retina is supported by both cocos2d 1.1 and 2.0

The suffix is

> -ipadhd